# How to display all campaign members in VisualForce

Tags: visualforce

I was looking at the Campaigns tab, and I wanted to make a VIsualForce page with a list of all the campaign members. Does anyone knows how to do this?

greetings,

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
list<campaignmember> myList{get; set;}
myList = new list<campaignmember>([select id,name from campaignmember]);
```

and display the list on your vf page.
Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I keep getting the error, that there is a compile error; unexpected token: '=' Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: In which line are you getting the error ?

Comment: In the line starting with myList =,

Comment: And it is about the first =

Comment: can you post the complete code you are using ? this type of error is easy to fix

Comment: Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: '=' at line 4 column 7